# How do I get the input value using it's id in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

This is the HTML code:

```html
<input id="billing:company" name="billing[company]" value = "1" type="text">
```

and this is the jQuery code:

```js
company = jQuery("#billing:company").val();
```

the company value is `undefined`. How do I get an input value that has a colon in its ID?

Comment: why does the id have a colon in the first place - i'm sure that isn't technically valid?

Comment: Is having ":" in id required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backslash for meta character such as `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ``:

```
company = jQuery("#billing\\:company").val();
```

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So, your usage of a colon in the ID is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to match the `id`:

```
company = jQuery("input[id='billing:company']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var company = jQuery("input[id='billing:company']").val();
        $("input[id='billing:company']").trigger('keyup');
        alert(company);
         $(document).delegate("input[id='billing:company']",'keyup',function(e){
        var company = company = jQuery("input[id='billing:company']").val();
        alert(company);
    });

    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="billing:company" name="billing[company]" value = "1" type="text">
</body>

</html>
```